# Combinação de duas listas em Python

Tags: python, lista, concatenação-de-string, combinações

Preciso de um código que descubra as possíveis senhas em um universo de LLLDDD (L=letra, d=dígito), achei mais fácil aplicar as condições separadamente e cheguei a duas listas:

```
lpossiveis:['ABD', 'ACD', 'ADB', 'ADC', 'ADE', 'ADF', 'AED', 'AFD', 'BAD', 'BDA', 'CAD', 'CDA', 'DAB', 'DAC', 'DAE', 'DAF', 'DBA', 'DCA', 'DEA', 'DFA', 'EAD', 'EDA', 'FAD', 'FDA']

dpossiveis: [314, 323, 332, 341, 611]
```

Agora preciso criar uma terceira lista entre a combinação das duas, onde o primeiro elemento de `lpossiveis` é concatenado com o primeiro elemento de `dpossiveis`, o primeiro elemento de `lpossiveis` é concatenado com o segundo elemento de `dpossiveis` e assim sucessivamente. O resultado deve ser:

```
senhas: ['ABC314', 'ABC323', 'ABC332', 'ABC341', 'ABC611', 'ACD314', ...  ]
```

Meu código está assim:

```
def senhaspossiveis(lpossiveis, dpossiveis):
    senhas = []
    for i in lpossiveis:
        for i in dpossiveis:
            senhas.append(lpossiveis[i], dpossiveis[i])
    return senhas
```

Mas não está criando a terceira lista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que o método `append` só recebe um argumento, mas você está passando dois: `lpossiveis[i]` e `dpossiveis[i]`.

Uma solução seria concatenar esses valores, como já sugeriram em outras respostas.

Mas se não for um exercício em que você precise fazer tudo manualmente, outra opção é usar o módulo `itertools`, que possui a função [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), que já cria essas combinações para você.

O único detalhe é que ela retorna as combinações em tuplas, então você tem que juntar os elementos de cada tupla em uma única string:

```
from itertools import product

lpossiveis = ['ABD', 'ACD', 'ADB', 'ADC', 'ADE', 'ADF', 'AED', 'AFD', 'BAD', 'BDA', 'CAD', 'CDA', 'DAB', 'DAC', 'DAE', 'DAF', 'DBA', 'DCA', 'DEA', 'DFA', 'EAD', 'EDA', 'FAD', 'FDA']
dpossiveis = [314, 323, 332, 341, 611]

senhas = [ f'{s}{num}' for s, num in product(lpossiveis, dpossiveis) ]
```

Ou, se precisar de uma função que faça isso:

```
from itertools import product

def senhas_possiveis(letras, numeros):
    return [ f'{s}{num}' for s, num in product(letras, numeros) ]

lpossiveis = ['ABD', 'ACD', 'ADB', 'ADC', 'ADE', 'ADF', 'AED', 'AFD', 'BAD', 'BDA', 'CAD', 'CDA', 'DAB', 'DAC', 'DAE', 'DAF', 'DBA', 'DCA', 'DEA', 'DFA', 'EAD', 'EDA', 'FAD', 'FDA']
dpossiveis = [314, 323, 332, 341, 611]
senhas = senhas_possiveis(lpossiveis, dpossiveis)
```

---

O detalhe é que o código acima cria uma lista com todas as senhas possíveis, e dependendo do tamanho das listas iniciais, ela pode ficar muito grande.

Se você precisa de fato de uma lista com todas as senhas, então deixe assim mesmo. Mas se você só precisa percorrer as senhas (em um `for`, por exemplo) e fazer algo com elas (e depois não vai precisar delas para mais nada), basta usar `product` diretamente no `for`:

```
for s, num in product(lpossiveis, dpossiveis):
    senha = f'{s}{num}'
    # fazer algo com a senha
```

A diferença é que `product` retorna um iterador que não computa todas as senhas de uma vez, e sim uma por vez (uma a cada iteração do `for`). Se a ideia é somente fazer algo com cada senha e depois não vai precisar delas para mais nada, isso é mais eficiente do que criar uma lista com todas as possibilidades (e essa abordagem se torna mais interessante se a quantidade de senhas possíveis for muito grande).

Mas se você precisa de uma lista com todas as senhas, aí não tem jeito, tem que criá-la mesmo.

Comment: Muito obrigada pela explicação! Estou iniciando na área e da maneira como explicou me fez entender várias coisas!

Answer (score 2):

Segue uma possível solução para o seu problema:

```
def senhaspossiveis(lpossiveis, dpossiveis):
    senhas = []
    for letras in lpossiveis:
        for  numeros in dpossiveis:
            combinacaosenha = letras+str(numeros)
            senhas.append(combinacaosenha)
    return senhas

lpossiveis = ['ABD', 'ACD', 'ADB', 'ADC', 'ADE', 'ADF', 'AED', 'AFD', 'BAD', 'BDA', 'CAD', 'CDA', 'DAB', 'DAC', 'DAE', 'DAF', 'DBA', 'DCA', 'DEA', 'DFA', 'EAD', 'EDA', 'FAD', 'FDA']
spossiveis = [314, 323, 332, 341, 611]

saida = senhaspossiveis(lpossiveis, spossiveis)

print(saida)
```

Answer (score 2):

Oi, Thais.
Fiz algumas mudanças no seu código e acho que deu certo.

Código:

```
def senhaspossiveis(lpossiveis, dpossiveis):
    senhas = []
    for l in lpossiveis:
        for d in dpossiveis:
            senhas.append(l + str(d))
    return senhas

lpossiveis = ['ABD', 'ACD', 'ADB', 'ADC', 'ADE', 'ADF', 'AED', 'AFD', 'BAD', 'BDA', 'CAD', 'CDA', 'DAB', 'DAC', 'DAE', 'DAF', 'DBA', 'DCA', 'DEA', 'DFA', 'EAD', 'EDA', 'FAD', 'FDA']
dpossiveis = [314, 323, 332, 341, 611]

senhas = senhaspossiveis(lpossiveis, dpossiveis)
```

Note que as iterações que estão ocorrendo no for são sobre os elementos das listas, e não sobre o index dos elementos das listas. Daí a concatenação é simples: l + str(d). A função str() transforma os inteiros de dpossiveis em string.

Bom dia!!

Comment: Deu certinho Carlos!! Muito obrigada!